# DTLS Handshake Key expiration Time Check

Tags: dtls

I have implemented DTLS PSK based security using Scandium library. I have used PSK keys from the third party. These PSK keys may be expired or not. So want to check in my implementation, PSK key is expired or not at the time of handshaking. Any way to check PSK is expired or not in Scandium library at the time of handshaking.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please indicate what you have done to resolve or find a solution. Please read the [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) section. Specifically the [How to post a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

[Answer from californium issues](https://github.com/eclipse/californium/issues/1071)

Maybe, you just have a wrong expectation about such a secret key for PSK. In differene to certificates, it doesn't contain any additional data as "expiration date", at least there is no common specification. So starting with

> These PSK keys may be expired or not.

it's unclear, how this should be determined.

> I have used PSK keys from the third party.

Therefore you may ask that third party, about that expiration.
I assume, it's just a extra field with an expiration date. If so,
implement a PskStore, which also contains such expiration dates and return null instead of the secret key on expiration.